# Local Declaration of NSMutableArray Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm adding an object to an `NSMutableArray` in this method:

```
 CarouselObject *objectModel = [[CarouselObject alloc]init];
        objectModel.name = [[d objectForKey:@"place"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        objectModel.address = [[d objectForKey:@"place"] objectForKey:@"address"];


        //cview = [[CaroView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 320, 170)];
        //cview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        //cview.images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.jpg"];

        if ([photo count] > 0) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[[photo objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"place_photo_reference"]);
            objectModel.imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.getnearest.com/api2/google_image.php?photoreference=%@&type=photo", [[photo objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"place_photo_reference"]];
  //                [cview.images setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objectModel.imageURL ] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.jpg"]];
 //                cview.images.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
//                cview.name.text = [[d valueForKey:@"place"] objectForKey:@"name"];
 //                cview.address.text = [[d valueForKey:@"place"] objectForKey:@"address"];
        } else if ([photo count] == 0) {
           objectModel.imageURL =  @"";
        }
        [carouselArray addObject:objectModel];
       // [responseScroll addSubview:cview];
       // x += 320;
    }
    [self  updateUI:carouselArray];
    //responseScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, 170);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

I'll need the array in this method:

```
   -(void)updateUI:carouselArray {

NSMutableArray *array;
array = carouselArray;

//carouselArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CGFloat x =0;
cview = [[CaroView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 320, 170)];

  }
```

I'm getting a warning telling me "Local declaration of carouselArray hides Instance variable" on every line I access `carouselArray` in `updateUI:`. I initialised the `NSMutableArray` in `viewDidLoad`, but I can't see why I'm having the problem.

Comment: Which line is the warning on, and what is the exact text of the warning?

Comment: Anytime I call carouselArray in this function (-(void)updateUI:carouselArray{}), I get that warning saying "Local declaration of carouselArray hides Instance variable"

Comment: And why did you declare carouselWarning locally?

Comment: You are declaring `carouselArray` as a parameter in the function header.  This "hides" the instance variable named `carouselArray`.  Maybe change the parameter to `carouselArrayParm` to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an instance variable called `carouselArray`, and you have a parameter named the same thing in `updateUI`.

Change this:

```
   -(void)updateUI:carouselArray {

NSMutableArray *array;
array = carouselArray;

//carouselArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CGFloat x =0;
cview = [[CaroView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 320, 170)];
}
```

to this:

```
-(void)updateUI:myArray {

NSMutableArray *array;
array = myArray;

//myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CGFloat x =0;
cview = [[CaroView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 320, 170)];

}
```

Comment: I did dis and it worked, but is it still possible to access the mutableArray i got in the former function in the new function?

Comment: @Sandspy Of course.  `myArray` and `array` in the second method are both the same array from the first method.

Answer (score 0):

> I get that warning saying "Local declaration of carouselArray hides
>   Instance variable"

Somewhere inside that method you are doing along the lines:

`NSMutableArray *carouselArray = ...`

The fact of you having an instance variable called `carouselArray` makes the compiler spit that warning.

---

Comment: @HermannKlecker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704454/local-declaration-of-nsmutablearray-warning/23704556?noredirect=1#comment36427145_23704454

Comment: The only place I'm initialising the MutableArray is in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-(void)updateUI:(NSMutableArray*)myCarouselArray {
```

...

```
array = myCarouselArray;
```

and go from there.

Comment: same thing is happening

Comment: Sorry, I mended the answer. Anyway, that warning should not do any harm. What you did is: You have an instance vairable called carouselArray. And then you declared a method parameter of the same name. That does generate a warning because `carouselArray` would then refer to the parameter within that method. AFAIK that is fine. You can still access the instance variable with `self.carouselArray` if it is a property or `self->carouselArray` if it is a regular iVar. IN the end it is just a warning and you did not do anything wrong with respect to the warning.

Comment: You don't need to use `self->` to access an ivar -- the compiler will insert that for you.

Comment: @jlehr, well that is right in principle. But in this case the method parameter myCarouselArray will hide the ivar because of the name conflict. Ant hat is what I meand. Even when the parameter has the same name then you can still access the ivar using self->...